# Deleting an entire directory with files and folders recursively

Tags: java, android

In my android code, the deleteRecursive method seems to work fine, but when i keep the code inside **onPostExecute** method, it shows error, saying

> cannot resolve method isDirectory(),
>   method call expected in deleteRecursive(child)
>   cannot resolve method delete()

here is my piece of code,

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
    super.onPostExecute(json);

    int success = 0;

    if (pDialog != null && pDialog.isShowing()) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }

    if (json != null) {
        try {
            success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    if (success == 1) {
        String fileOrDirectory = finalSavePath + "/";
        public void deleteRecursive(File fileOrDirectory) {
            if (fileOrDirectory.isDirectory()) {
                for (File child : fileOrDirectory.listFiles()) {
                    deleteRecursive(child);
                }
                fileOrDirectory.delete();
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Sorry, cannot Delete", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

I understand that there is something very silly which i am missing, nut any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you can not make a method inside your if else statement

Try this

```
 public static void deleteFilesAndFolders(File fileOrDirectory) {

    if (fileOrDirectory.isDirectory())
        for (File child : fileOrDirectory.listFiles())
            deleteFilesAndFolders(child);

    fileOrDirectory.delete();

}
```

call deleteFilesAndFolders(fileOrDirectory) directly in your statement.

Answer (score 0):

You have created function inside function, that's the problem.

Try with changing your code as below...

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
    super.onPostExecute(json);


    int success = 0;

    if (pDialog != null && pDialog.isShowing()) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }

    if (json != null) {
        try {
            success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    if (success == 1) {
        String fileOrDirectory = finalSavePath + "/";
        deleteRecursive(new File(fileOrDirectory));

    }else{
        Toast.makeText(context, "Sorry, cannot Delete", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}



public void deleteRecursive(File fileOrDirectory) {
    if (fileOrDirectory.isDirectory())
        for (File child : fileOrDirectory.listFiles())
            deleteRecursive(child);

    fileOrDirectory.delete();
}
```

Comment: It should be deleteRecursive(new File(fileOrDirectory), instead of deleteRecursive(fileOrDirectory).

Comment: @priyank patel, you are not a great programmer, but a good programmer with great habits. Thanks a bunch man. You removed tons of headache.

Comment: @priya Thanks, happy to help you.